# Source maps not working with Gulp, Browserify, Babelify, Uglify, gulp-rename, and gulp-sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, source-maps

I'm working on a project that uses the following tools:

- [Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp)
- [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)
- [Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify)
- [Uglify](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify)
- [gulp-rename](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename)
- [gulp-sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps)

I'm able to generate the distribution file and it works correctly. The generated source map is not correct though. When I load it in Chrome, Chrome  not able to map the distribution file to the source files. My problem is similar (but not the same) to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160787/browserify-babelify-uglify-source-map-sources-do-not-get-loaded-in-google-chrome). Unfortunately, this similar issue doesn't have an answer, thus it doesn't help me.

I've also tried to follow [this recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md), but it doesn't fit my case.

This is the relevant code of my set up (`gulpfile.js`):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('build:dist', function() {
   var browserifyInstance = browserify({
      entries: 'src/module.js',
      debug: true,
      standalone: 'Module',
      bundleExternal: false,
      transform: [babelify]
   });

   return browserifyInstance
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('module.js'))
      .pipe(rename({
         extname: '.min.js'
      }))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
         loadMaps: true
      }))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I know my comment is not very constructive; but just one question: why would you want sourcemaps on a build distribution ? I mean, why would you uglify file and include sourcemaps ? If you uglify, that means you want to "obscure" your code, so, why sourcemaps ?

Comment: Minification is not to obscure code, it's to save bandwidth to your users. The less the size, the faster the loading time of your website.

Comment: Yeah, well, I know that, but why would you need them on a production environment ? Use them locally was my point...

Comment: Sometimes you have a bug that happens in production but not on your machine/stage machine. With source maps you can easy find the problem.

Comment: Ok, it seems like is a common thing so far: https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/issues/64 Thats why I was suggesting not to use sourcemaps on prod. but if there is no other option, you have to check that issue and see what you can do. Good luck :)